# How to get the position of an element after css animation (vanilla js)

Tags: javascript, css-animations

I'm working on a project involving multiple animations, and while most of them are easily done with css keyframe animations, others require javascript and I'm kinda in the weeds with how to execute those. I'll do my best to describe what I cannot show in a fiddle (I'm coding what's demo'd in a video).

There are several sections in the page, each of which has various elements fading in and out, rotating, etc. When each section is scrolled into view an 'animate' class is added to it to trigger the css animations, one of which is an svg element descending from north of the viewport to the bottom of the viewport where it parks. But then, when the user continues to scroll down I need to animate this svg element out of view south of the viewport, and then re-enter as the next section is scrolled into view. So I'm trying to get the position (vanilla js please) of the element in the findSection function when it's parked, i.e., *after its keyframe animation is complete* but the methods I've tried so far are getting instead the pre-animation position. How can I get the current position of an absolutely positioned element *after* it's been animated via css? And I'm all ears if there's an overall better approach than what I'm doing thus far, especially if I can use a single svg element instead of duping it in each section.

Many thanks for any help/suggestions.

Whiskey T.

markup (each section):

```
<div class="section" id="section-1">
    <svg version="1.1" class="thing-svg" [ etc. ] >
        <g class="thing-path-group">
            <path class="thing-path" d=" ... " />
        </g>
    </svg>
    <!-- content -->
</div><!-- #section-1 -->
```

css:

```
.thing-svg {
    position: absolute;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    left: calc(50% - 30px);
    top: -60px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 9;
}

.animate .thing-svg {
    animation: dropIt 1.8s ease-in-out forwards .3s;
}

@keyframes dropIt {
    0% {
        top: -60px;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    3% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        top: calc(100vh - 60px);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

javascript:

```
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.section');
const svgEl = document.querySelector('#svg-el');


window.addEventListener('scroll', debounce(findSection)); // yes, there's a debounce fn

function findSection(e) {

    let svgElPosition = svgEl.getBoundingClientRect();

    sections.forEach(section => {

        const sectionInAt = (window.scrollY + window.innerHeight) - section.offsetHeight / 2;

        // these both get the pre-css keyframe animation value of 'top', but I need the post-keyframe animation 'top' value
        console.log("svgElPosition.top", svgElPosition.top);
        console.log(window.getComputedStyle(svgEl, null).getPropertyValue("top"));


        // bottom of the section:
        const sectionBottom = section.offsetTop + section.offsetHeight;

        // isHalfShown is true while sectionInAt/triggerCoord > section.offsetTop (i.e., section is half viz)
        const isHalfShown = sectionInAt > section.offsetTop;

        // isNotScrolledPast is true while window.scrollY < imageBottom (i.e., image is still viz)
        const isNotScrolledPast = window.scrollY < sectionBottom;

        if (isHalfShown && isNotScrolledPast) {
            section.classList.add('animate');
        } else {
            section.classList.remove('animate');
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should register an [animationend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/animationend) event listener on your element:

```
svgEl.addEventListener('animationend', function (event) {
    const svgRect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
});
```

This fires whenever a CSS animation has finished on your element and is the surefire way to know that it has completed. Also note you make be able to make use of [animationstart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/animationstart), [animationiteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/animationiteration), and [animationcancel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/animationcancel) events.

Comment: Thank you skyline3000 and apologies for the delayed acknowledgement but I've been unable to post for a few days. Many thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I believe your best bet would be to use a setTimeout() to wait for the appropriate amount of time for the animation to complete, then get the position in the closure function.  Here's an example snippet:

```
if (isHalfShown && isNotScrolledPast) {
    section.classList.add('animate');
    let timer = setTimeout(function() {
    let rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log(rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom, rect.left);
    },300); //.3 seconds, if I read that correctly from the CSS (maybe an extra .01 seconds or something as well for good measure)
}
```

The "timer" variable is not explicitly used in this example, but it may be useful if you ever need to cancel an animation to cancel the timer as well (though you will need to take the scope outside of this conditional statement).

Comment: Thanks for the help, apologies for my late response, been swamped on another project. I'll have a go with this 'tho I suspect @skyline3000's suggestion is the one I was anticipating

Comment: Thanks Brandon but I think I'll have to work with the animation events skyline3000 mentioned. I did try the timeout as you suggested (and w/longer timeout to be sure) but still got the pre-animation position.